# Vue.js shared input data across components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, filter, vuejs2, vue-component

I have 4 components that display different data. In each component I have a navigation bar that contains an input, which I use to filter the data in the component, like this:

```js
computed: {
  filteredItems() {
    if (this.search !== '') {
      return this.allManufacturers.filter(item => {
        return item.id.toUpperCase().startsWith(this.search.toUpperCase()) === true
      })
    }
    return this.cars.filter(item => {
      return item.id.toUpperCase().startsWith(this.search.toUpperCase()) === true
    })
  },
},
```

The computed property is different in the 4 components.
I want to move the navigation bar to a component and filter using the input in the navigation bar rather than duplicating the code in each component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a navigation bar component that will `$emit` a `search` event containing the searched value.  It only has a template:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <input @input="$emit('search', $event)" />
  </div>
</template>
```

You can use that in any of your other components like this:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <navigation @search="newSearch($event.target.value)"></navigation>
    {{ filteredItems }}
  </div>
</template>
```

```js
data() {
  return {
    search: ''
  }
},
computed: {
  filteredItems () {
    if (this.search !== '') {
      return this.allManufacturers.filter(item => {
        return item.id.toUpperCase().startsWith(this.search.toUpperCase()) === true
      })
    }
    return this.cars.filter(item => {
      return item.id.toUpperCase().startsWith(this.search.toUpperCase()) === true
    })
  },
},
methods: {
  newSearch(text) {
    this.search = text;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but your solution is working fine with input but with v-text-field is not sending the value

Comment: You haven't mentioned Vuetify or `v-text-field` anywhere until now.  For that, change this:  `$event.target.value` to just `$event`